# angular event.preventDefault() on run methode

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Am trying to route user to specific state when angular start, but it doesn't go to login when if it is true, instead of it goes to default routState

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state) {

var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')
var shouldChangePassword=window.localStorage.getItem('shouldChangePassword')
if (authToken == 'undefined' || shouldChangePassword == 'true') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');

    return;
}
.config(
//my routes

.state('login', {
           url: '/login',
           templateUrl: 'templates/account_login.html',
           controller: 'loginCtrl',
       })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/category');
)
```

how can i redirect to login and stop the app from going to default route

Comment: have you checked if the condition in the if block evaluates to true?

Comment: yes the condition is true , i have checked it with dev tools open , it even hit $state.go('login')

Comment: It hits the $state.go('login')? I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: it hit $state.go('login'); but it doesnt go to that state , it goes to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise which is /tab/category'

Comment: is the 'login' state defined? I'm guessing it tries to redirect to the login but doesn't find it, so the otherwise is called. You should check the name of the login state if it matches, or paste your routes definition here

Comment: yes it is defined , i updated the code above

Comment: where is the `event` defined?

Comment: event is on windows object

Comment: if (authToken == 'undefined' || shouldChangePassword == 'true') {                                               $rootScope.on('click', function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $state.go('login');
}
    return;
}

Comment: event is not defined..

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking to [UI-router's $stateChangeStart](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) state change event:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
        var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('authToken');
        var shouldChangePassword=window.localStorage.getItem('shouldChangePassword');
        if (!authToken || shouldChangePassword) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
```

But you might consider moving the authToken and shouldChangePassword to a separate service and read/set the value from/to that service instead of reading from the localstorage for every state change